# Place image between 2 divs (centered on screen, responsive and not over text)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to place an image between 2 divs on my page.  I have currently been able to get an image between the two divs, but it isn't responsive (only in the correct position at 1920 width) and it overlaps the text of both divs:

[screenshot from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1FWn.jpg)

css

```
.btwimg {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(-20%, -50%, 0);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    background: url("../img/lara2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

html

```
<div class="btwimg">
    <img src="img/lara2.png">
</div>
```

[what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Tpg.jpg)

Is it possible to achieve what I'm after?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: give padding to your texts.

Comment: I don't see two divs in the markup you give. What is the purpose of the div around the img? Where is the CSS for the other divs? What do you mean by "responsive"? In most cases, people really mean "adaptive" but what are those elements supposed to do and when?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add the same amount of `padding-bottom` to the upper DIV and `padding-top` to the subsequent DIV to create enogh space for your image. (trial and error to find the right amount)

Your `btwing` DIV should be a child element of the subsequent DIV. Then this CSS should work:

```
.btwimg {
  width: 90%;
  height: 250px /* Just a random guess - Needs a fixed height! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url("../img/lara2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Actually the `height`  setting should be a `calc` value which is derived from the original width/height proportion and the 90% width you set, like `height: calc(9/16 * 90%);`if the proportion is 16/9

Comment: to make it responsive, use position as relative.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh no - then you would loose the overlapping / partly covering of the other DIVs

Answer (score 0):

I took @Johannes answer and tweaked a little to get the result I wanted:

```
.btwimg {
max-width: 800px;
min-width: 300px;
height: 16vw;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: 50%;
top: calc(2vw  - 38px); /* keeps div roughly centred at all target resolutions */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I then used an image rather than a background to make the re-sizing easier.

```
.btwimg img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

btwimg was put as a child of the 2nd div as recommended

[result at mobile resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcPlF.png)

[result at desktop resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Elg.jpg)